# Empty cursor row when filtering with selection

Tags: android, where-clause, android-cursor

I'm not confident with cursors and I'm facing some problem when filtering one with a WHERE clause.

What I'm doing:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uriConversation = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");

    String[] projection = new String[]{"*"};
    String selection = "address=" + phoneNumberForThread;

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uriConversation, projection, null, null, null);
```

Executing this code the cursor get filled and works perfectly.
However, if I swap the null selection argument with my selection String as

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uriConversation, projection, selection, null, null);
```

I then get an empty cursor. I even check for `!phoneNumberForThread.isEmpty()`

I think I'm doing something wrong but again I am not confident with cursor yet.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess here, but if address is a string, shouldn't it be enclosed by `'`? Like: `String selection = "address='" + phoneNumberForThread + "'";`

Comment: you should run without selection and go with debugger over the cursor so you can check if you have "address" field and what is the "value" of it. After you have something that you know for sure that it have to return at least 1 record test again and see which syntax issue you have

Comment: @danysz exactly what I tried so far. I think that Marcus may be right about the enclosing. I will test this as soon as possible and let you know.

Comment: @Marcus you were right. Please write your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input variabel is stored as a `string` data type, you should enclose it with `'` as such:

`String selection = "address='" + phoneNumberForThread + "'";`